# Problemas renderizacion con Angular4/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

En relación a `Angular 4`, cuando hago modificaciones en las `variables` que son llamadas a través de `{{ }}`, no se produce ningún cambio en el `html`. Además, si escribo el comando `ng serve`, me da el siguiente error:

> Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.

AL comprobar que version tengo con el comando ng -v, da el siguiente error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\usuario\node_modules'
>       at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:904:18)
>       at VersionCommand.run (C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\version.js:55:41)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:150:28)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at fulfilled (C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular  \cli\models\command-runner.js:11:58)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:612:3

Answer (score 0):

suena a un problema de version de tu cli, puedes revisar en tu pakage.json si es igual a la version que tienes instalada, puedes ver la version instalada usando

```
ng -v
```

una vez que compruebes el error, puedes o dar un update de tu cli, o un downgrade:

```
// Downgrade
npm uninstall -D @angular/cli // siendo -D tu proyecto local
npm install -D @angular/cli@x.x.x // siendo x.x.x la version a la que quieres bajar.
si quieres la ultima version en lugar de los numeros de version usa latest


// Update
npm install -g @angular/cli@x.x.x // esto actualizara la version global de tu cli, siendo -g global, es decir actualizaras globalmente el cli.
si quieres la ultima version en lugar de los numeros de version usa latest
```

Es importante tener ambas versiones, global y local en la misma version, pues la ultima version del cli dejo de usar **.angular-cli.json** y a su vez este comenzo a utilizar **angular.json**.

Comment: Gracias por responder. He intentado hacer lo primero que indicas, comprobar la version instalada. Pero da error. He editado mi publicación mas arriba explicando el resultado ya que no cabía como comentario

Comment: intenta instalar los paquetes nuevamente, elimina tu node_modules y tu package-lock.json y dale a npm install

Comment: Lo he eliminado todo. He entrado en la web de node.js y he realizado la instalación. Voy a la consola y escribo: node -v y dice: `node no se reconoce como comando` (lo mismo con npm -v)

Comment: definitivamente tienes un problema con tu instalacion de node. Debes realizar un instalacion limpia de ambos, asegurandote de seguir la guia oficial de node y npm, si estas en windows tal vez debas agregar a node y npm a tu variable path. https://love2dev.com/blog/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/